# Date time compare to get exact seconds

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any way to directly get the seconds using date time diff or any library, API, sample code, without using conversion like hrs to mins, mins to sec etc..? because I just need the seconds date, hrs, mins will be ignored,

Example:

```
10/28/2015 08:54:54 - 10/28/2015 07:54:54 = 3600 seconds
10/28/2015 08:54:54 - 10/27/2015 07:54:54 = 90000 seconds
10/28/2015 08:54:54 - 10/28/2015 08:54:10 = 44 seconds
```

Note: Using this format (time.strftime("%m/%d/%y  %I:%M:%S")) as datetime

I am using this link as my reference http://www.onlineconversion.com/days_between_advanced.htm

Comment: What does the input look like? Is it strings? if string, what does the string look like>

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you link me where is the duplicate question for this, as my reference

Comment: It is linked automatically.

Comment: from my code it is string and Im using this format (time.strftime("%m/%d/%y  %I:%M:%S"))

Comment: I see, but in my case it was a string it was inputed and did not came from the database as timestamp.

Comment: If you're using `strftime()`, you're starting with `datetime` or `time` objects. Use them.

Comment: unrelated: don't use `%y` (two digit year), use `%Y` (4 digits) instead. don't use `%I` (12hours) format without `%p`, use `%H` (24hours) instead. To get datetime from the time string: `d = datetime.strptime('10/28/2015 08:54:10', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`